# Need to apply jquery different functions to each DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, modx

I have jquery code:

```
$(".gametime").append(moment.tz('16/3/0:45', 'DD/MMMM/HH/mm', 'Europe/Moscow').tz(user_tz).format('DD MMMM HH:mm'));
$(".gametime2").append(moment.tz('16/3/0:45', 'DD/MMMM/HH/mm', 'Europe/Moscow').tz(user_tz).format('DD MMMM HH:mm'));
```

and 2 tag p with class gametime

```
<p class="gametime1"></p>

<p class="gametime2"></p>
```

Need to create element (gametime), and when i create that, it will have number (1 or 2 or 3...), and also need to apply different codes to created element. Like automized. I want to integrate all of that with MODX so... Who can help?)

Comment: not very clear what you need

Comment: hi! Your question is very unclear. Could you provide us with more information? What are you trying to accomplish on the whole?